# GraphQL query in swift IOS application using AWS app sync not executing (getting skipped)

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to query dynamoDB using AWS App sync codegen feature in iOS app. DynamoDB resolvers have also been created. I am able to query the table from the app sync explorer, However when  I execute the code, the query statement just gets skipped ... or does nothing.

```
func queryProfile() {
        print("I Am Here1")
        //appSyncClient?.fetch(query: GetSkill2CustomerEvQuery(skill: "Doctor")) { result, error in
        //appSyncClient?.fetch(query: ListSkill2CustomerEvsQuery()) { (result, error) in
        appSyncClient?.fetch(query: GetSkill2CustomerEvQuery(skill: "Doctor"), cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataAndFetch)  { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
                print("I Am Here3")
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                return
            }

            print("I Am Here2")
            print(result.debugDescription)
           // print(result?.data?.getSkill2CustomerEv?.userId! as Any)
        }
        print("I Am Here4")
    }
```

> ```
>  output: 
>  I Am Here1
>  I Am Here4
> ```

Comment: Can someone please advise...

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet you used for initializing the AppSync client?

Comment: Also, Can you open a Github issue at https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios for better traction?

Comment: I have opened a GitHub issue https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios/issues/269